# Stick a UILable to UIView or UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, touch, subview

I have a subview in my app that contains a UIImageView. The user can touch this subview and move it around. I have some UILabels that I want to "stick" or group with the subview so that they move along with it. I wonder how to do that?
Here is where I add the Labels to the subview:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

//Decrease the site of root CALayer of the view and give it round corners
self.view.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
self.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.view.layer.frame = CGRectInset(self.view.layer.frame, 40, 40);

//check if the background is from the photo library and create a sublayer for the semi transparent white badge and a textsublayer for the countdown labels. Also hide the regular view labels


NSString *path = [_occasion imagePath];

if (path != nil && [path hasPrefix:@"ass"])
{

    //Make a subview with a UIImageView inside for the badge
    CGRect  badgeRect = CGRectMake(32, 13, 236, 222);
    UIView *badge = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:badgeRect];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:[badge frame]];

    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"badge.png"]];

    [badge addSubview:imageView];

    [self.view addSubview:badge];

    /*[self.view bringSubviewToFront:countDownLabel];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:daysLabel];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:hoursLabel];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:minutesLabel];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:secondsLabel];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:daysName];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:hoursName];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:minutesName];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:secondsName];*/

    [badge addSubview:countDownLabel];
    [badge addSubview:daysLabel];
    [badge addSubview:hoursLabel];
    [badge addSubview:minutesLabel];
    [badge addSubview:secondsLabel];
    [badge addSubview:daysName];
    [badge addSubview:hoursName];
    [badge addSubview:minutesName];
    [badge addSubview:secondsName];
//more code for recognizing the touches on the subview
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put them on the UIImageView and they'll move along with it.

Comment: I did try to add them to the subview but they don't move along.

Comment: Dont't get me wrong. You don't have to put the labels on the same subview as the UIImageView, but ON the UIImageView. If they don't should appear ON the Image use a transparent container view with the UIImageView AND the labels on it and move that one.

Comment: Oh I did get you wrong. I'll try adding them to the UIImageView and see what happens.

Comment: Yup. That worked. Adding the UILabel s tot eh UIImageView. Please edit your answer to UIImageView instead of UIView and I'll accept it. Thanks a lot. Here is the new code: `[imageView addSubview:countDownLabel];
        [imageView addSubview:daysLabel];
        [imageView addSubview:hoursLabel];
        [imageView addSubview:minutesLabel];
        [imageView addSubview:secondsLabel];
        [imageView addSubview:daysName];
        [imageView addSubview:hoursName];
        [imageView addSubview:minutesName];
        [imageView addSubview:secondsName];`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the position of your subview and change the position of you labels according to that.

Comment: Isn't there a simpler way? cuz I have about 9 labels and keeping them aligned this way would be a little hard I guess.